# SQL - filtering with "min" and groupby

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to come up with a query which does "min" calculation along with the filter(status='PENDING') so that it returns the correct **min_id**. Simply adding it in the where clause wouldn't solve my purpose. It might be easier to understand with the information below:

```
Table: 

  id    sub_id         status      il_flag

  21     889          FAILED       false
  22     889          PENDING      false
  23     889          PENDING      false
```

MyQuery:

```
select sub_id, 
       min(id) as min_id, 
       sum(case when status = 'PENDING' then 1 else 0 end) as pending_count,
       sum(case when status in ('ACCEPTED','FAILED') then 1 else 0 end) as invalid_count
    from sub_event where il_flag=false
    group by sub_id
```

Result from above query (returns **Incorrect 'min_id'**):

```
sub_id  min_id  valid_count  invalid_count
 889      21       2            1
```

Expected result(minimum id of status='PENDING'):

```
sub_id  min_id  valid_count  invalid_count
 889      22       2            1
```

In the above query, simply adding "status='PENDING'" in '*where*' clause wouldn't solve my purpose because then we wont get the *invalid_count*.

I am using postgres 9.6

Thanks in advance !

Comment: use `min(case when status = 'PENDING' then id end)` instead of `min(id)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
  min(case when status = 'PENDING' then id end) as min_pending_id,
```

Or, better yet, use `filter`:

```
min(id) filter (where status = 'PENDING')
```

The latter was introduced in Postgres 9.4, is not compatible with most other databases, and should have slightly better performance (it is consistent with the ANSI standard).

EDIT:

In fact, you can write the whole query as:

```
select sub_id, 
       min(id) filter (where status = 'PENDING') as min_id, 
       count(*) filter (where status = 'PENDING') as pending_count,
       count(*) filter (where status in ('ACCEPTED', 'FAILED')) as invalid_count
from subscription_event
where idl_flag = false
group by sub_id;
```

The more I use the `filter` clause, the more I like it.  Never use `case` in an aggregation again!